# In Mongo-DB How to set Default Value for a field through node restify?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, restify

I have created a collection(table) named Group and I have fields such as Group name,Group Desc and Group Type but I need to set the Group type by default to 1 if it receives a null value. And I have the following code to insert.

```
function postNewGroups(req , res , next){

var Group = {};
Group._id = sequence;
Group.GROUP_NAME = req.params.GROUP_NAME;
Group.GROUP_DESC = req.params.GROUP_DESC;
Group.GROUP_TYPE = req.params.GROUP_TYPE;

Groups.save(Group , function(err , success){
        console.log('Response success '+success);
        console.log('Response error '+err);
        if(success){
            res.send(201 , Group);
            return next();
        }else{
            return next(err);
        }
    });
```

But I have searched lot about how to set a default value but I couldn't able to find a solution.

Comment: Mongodb is unstructural database ,So in DB Level you can't assign default value to 1 for Group type ,while saving, every time you need to set as 1 in your code level.And any way you are assing the value then why you need default value..????

Comment: Ok, And also i want to know how to set the data types for each fields in collection in mongodb using node restify

Comment: I am not much familiar with restify/node.js. In Mongodb when ever you are communicating with other language then data type of it's structure is depend upon respective language,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to set default value while inserting data in MongoDb, Use **mongoose**.
It has functionality multiple functionality given below and many more.
for Ex.

```
{
organization:{
  type: string,
  default: "XYZ"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you need some structures like default values and variable types use [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/)
You could set schemas and defaults like so:
new Schema({
date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})